# Adding prefix to row value based on other dataframes. Python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

```
I have two dataframe the 1st one
     CallId  ScoreId       ScoreName  Weight
19   4198451      180         First     1.0
110  4198451      348        Second     3.0
124  4198451      15         Third      1.0


The second
      CallId       ScoreComponentName  ScoreId  Weight
58   4198451                 Dissat      180     1.0
59   4198451             Escalation      180     0.0
60   4198451                 Repeat      180     0.0
61   4198451               Transfer      180     0.0
363  4198451                Account      348     0.0
364  4198451             Activation      348     0.0
375  4198451             Categories       15     0.0
```

Now for each value under Scorecomponentname I want to add a prefix base on the Scorename for each ScoreId

How can I have this result?
expected result:

```
     CallId       ScoreComponentName  ScoreId  Weight
58   4198451           First.Dissat      180     1.0
59   4198451       First.Escalation      180     0.0
60   4198451           First.Repeat      180     0.0
61   4198451         First.Transfer      180     0.0
363  4198451         Second.Account      348     0.0
364  4198451       Second.Activation     348     0.0
375  4198451        Third.Categories      15     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge and sum columns like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
           {"A":[45,67,12,78,92,65,89,12,34,78],
            "component":["h","b","f","d","e","t","y","p","w","q"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
           {"A":[45,67,12],
            "name":['First','Second','Third']})

new=df.merge(df2,how='left',on='A')
new['component']+'.'+new['name']
```